# How to pass variable to href in javascript?

Tags: javascript, href, location-href

How to pass this variable value here? Below code is not working. And all other discussions on Stackoverflow are unclear.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function check()
        {
            var dist = document.getElementById('value');
            if (dist!=""){
                window.location.href="district.php?dist="+dist;
            }
            else
               alert('Oops.!!');
        }
</script>
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<select id="value" name="dist" onchange="return check()">
```

Comment: You may want to encode it as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to fetch field value using `.value` as you are passing whole object to the URL as `document.getElementbyId('value')` returns whole field object.

```
var dist = document.getElementById('value').value;
```

So your function should be like this

```
function check() {
    var dist = document.getElementById('value').value; // change here
    if (dist != "") {
        window.location.href = "district.php?dist=" + dist;
    } else
        alert('Oops.!!');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have fetch `value` of the field, Currently you are using DOM object

Use

```
 var dist = document.getElementById('value').value;
```

### OR

Use

```
 if (dist.value!=""){
     window.location.href="district.php?dist="+dist.value;
```

instead of

```
if (dist!=""){
     window.location.href="district.php?dist="+dist;
```

Comment: @Joel, upvoted your question soon you will enough reputation to upvote. As far I am concerned Its more important to help a fellow community member than reputation point. Mary x-mas

Comment: Merry x'mas dude :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function check() {
    var dist = document.getElementById('value').value;

    if (dist) {
        window.location.href = "district.php?dist=" + dist;
    } else {
        alert('Oops.!!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var dist = document.getElementById('value').value;
if (dist != "") {
 window.location.href="district.php?dist="+dist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some correction in your function..

```
function check()
    {
        var dist = document.getElementById('value').value;  //for input text value
       if (dist!==""){  //  for comparision
           window.location.href="district.php?dist="+dist;
       }
       else
           alert('Oops.!!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a very different approach to this.  I set browser cookies in the client that expire a second after I set `window.location.href`.

This is way more secure than embedding your parameters in the URL.

The server receives the parameters as cookies, and the browser deletes the cookies right after they are sent.

```js
const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 1000).toUTCString()
document.cookie = `oauth-username=user123; expires=${expires}`
window.location.href = `https:foo.com/oauth/google/link`
```