# how to pass variable value in window.location.href in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

In this code work well and show all data.this is the piece of javascript code

checkoutCart:

```
function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
        var checkoutString = "Total Price: " + totalPrice + "\nTotal Quantity: " + totalQuantity;
        checkoutString += "\n\n id \t name \t summary \t price \t quantity \t image path";
        $.each(products, function(){
          checkoutString += ("\n " + this.id + " \t " + this.name + " \t " + this.summary + " \t " + this.price + " \t " + this.quantity + " \t " + this.image);
        });
    alert(checkoutString)
```

after this code, I am wanted to use href attribute  with id passing.after the working of alert function then press ok button after that my href link work well but show in url bar order.php?id=undefined . here is code

```
window.location.href="order.php?id="+this.id ;
```

Comment: Have you check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769299/how-to-pass-variable-to-href-in-javascript

Comment: in my case this solution not work for me because I have shopping cart code that take value dynamically

Comment: In the foreach Loop, this.id is the ids of the products added to cart. In redirect link you need the order id. But order id is not define any where!