# How to send Parametrs with windows.location.hrf using Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 pages A and B. I want to send parameters from page A to page B using windows.location.hrf. Exemple window.location.hrf ="www.gogle.com"

Comment: Hi Dan! This is a question better suited for Google. You can search your exact title within Google and find the answer as the first result!

Comment: @Phil is right, and Google will even correct your typo!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable to href in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769299/how-to-pass-variable-to-href-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it pass value as in below example.

window.location.href = "www.google.com?parm=" + paramvalue;

Comment: Thank you, and how you can get this value with this parameter on page B ?

Comment: Check below link which explains the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript